# Preg_replace non-alphanumerics and special characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to use preg_replace to remove any characters in a string that fall outside the specified whitelist.  The whitelist should contain all alphanumerics and common punctuation, as well as spaces and the following: ² ¹ º ° © ½ ¼ ¾ ® ™

I attempted to use the following to accomplish this:

```
preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:punct:] ²¹º°©½¼¾®™]/","", $string);
```

However, this removes everything on the string that comes after an illegal character, instead of removing ONLY the illegal characters.  It works as desired if I only use the alnum, punct, and space character, so I think the problem lies with the special characters at the end - but I am having trouble figuring out how to include them properly.

Example:

"test test ₣ test test" becomes "test test ", but I want it to become "test test test test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`u` (*unicode*) **modifier**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers).

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:][:punct:] ²¹º°©½¼¾®™]/u', '', $str);
```